# Identifying Double match in IF statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have a following formula looking at postcode value from one column and comparing it against the range of postecode data in another column. If the postcode exist it will return true and if it does not then it will return the postcode which does not exist. What I also want this formula to do to check if more then one value exist in case of TRUE and if it does then say the number of mathes rather then TRUE. But if only 1 match exist then simply say TRUE.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C8,$P$2:$P$572,0)),C8,"TRUE")
```

Comment: I'm going to assume you're talking about Excel formulas?

Comment: Yes you are correct, my apologies as I did not mentione this in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SumProduct](http://blogs.office.com/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/) to  count multiple matches

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($P$2:$P$572=C8)*($P$2:$P$572=C8))=0,C8,IF(SUMPRODUCT(($P$2:$P$572=C8)*($P$2:$P$572=C8))=1,TRUE,SUMPRODUCT(($P$2:$P$572=C8)*($P$2:$P$572=C8))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF()` in combination with IF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($P$2:$P$572, C8)=0, C8, IF(COUNTIF($P$2:$P$572, C8)=1, "TRUE", COUNTIF($P$2:$P$572, C8))
```

and perhaps reduce the number of `COUNTIF`s by adding another column.